# UBUNTU + extract filesystem.squashfs for editing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, squashfs

please advice how to install the squashfs-tools
 on UBUNTU linux ?

I try this

```
  unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs

  The program 'unsquashfs' is currently not installed, You can install it by typing:
```

.

so I want to install as the following:

```
   sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools

   E: Unable to locate package  squashfs-tools
```